# Different behaviors when linking with extern int value and function

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

The method below is a Objective-C method and its assembly code generated by LLVM.

```
extern int globalInt ;

- (void)systemInfo
{
    add_fun(globalInt, 2) ;
}
```

---

```
    .align  2
    .code   16                      @ @"\01-[utility systemInfo]"
    .thumb_func "-[utility systemInfo]"
"-[utility systemInfo]":
Lfunc_begin2:
    .loc    1 31 0
    .cfi_startproc
@ BB#0:
    push    {r7, lr}
    mov r7, sp
    sub sp, #12
    movs    r2, #2
    movt    r2, #0
    movw    r3, :lower16:(L_globalInt$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC2_0+4))
    movt    r3, :upper16:(L_globalInt$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC2_0+4))
LPC2_0:
    add r3, pc
    ldr r3, [r3]
    str r0, [sp, #8]
    str r1, [sp, #4]
    .loc    1 33 0 prologue_end
Ltmp6:
    ldr r0, [r3]
    mov r1, r2
    bl  _add_fun
    .loc    1 34 0
    str r0, [sp]                @ 4-byte Spill
    add sp, #12
    pop {r7, pc}
Ltmp7:
Lfunc_end2:
    .cfi_endproc
```

---

```
L_globalInt$non_lazy_ptr:
    .indirect_symbol    _globalInt
    .long   0
```

Both `globalInt` and `add_fun` are defined in another source file. In the assembly code, it use the name of `add_fun`, but to `globalInt` it use a relative-pc style code to get its value. **why can't the `globalInt` be used in this way ?**

```
movw r3, :lower16(_globalInt)
movt r3, :upper16(_globalInt)
ldr  r3, [r3]
```

Comment: ARM processors have fixed-size instructions, so there are only so many bits available to encode address displacements. The `BL` instruction has a lot of bits reserved for the displacement, so it can encode displacements from +/-4MB up to +/- 32MB, depending on the mode the processor's in. In 16-bit Thumb code this is accomplished by actually encoding `BL` as two related halfwords instead of a single halfword like other instructions.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I think my bad explanation make you misunderstand, I have edited my question to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If `globalInt` was static / constant in some way compiler would try to embed the value into the instruction, however ARM is a load/store architecture and for most cases to do operations on values it needs to load them to registers first.

Here it is as direct as it can get.

```
movw    r3, :lower16:(L_globalInt$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC2_0+4))
movt    r3, :upper16:(L_globalInt$non_lazy_ptr-(LPC2_0+4))
```

Here address will be embedded into instruction.

```
bl  _add_fun
```

Comment: @KudoCC That's probably due to compiling or linking. It won't be some extra calculation in the result binary.